# Ubuntu directory for storing files

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a server running on Ubuntu which creates lots of data and media files. I would like to know what is the best location to store the files.

Requirment :

My application running on java server(tomcat) needs to read, write and delete these files. 
There could be 100s of these files and the files could be huge.

I would like to know what is the best location(directory) for storing the files.

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'? What are your requirements?

Comment: The other question is what this has to do with programming.  This could perhaps be asked on Server Fault (if firemonkey is administering the server for pay), or possibly Super User, and the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange site (or maybe the Ubuntu one) would be good forums for this (if more specifically written).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being linux, there are several possible locations that make sense.  There is no technical limitation on where they can go - tomcat can access them anywhere.  If it were me, I think I might choose this structure:

> `/var/<app>/media/`
>
> `/var/<app>/data/`

(where `<app>`  is the name of your app)

Comment: thank you ... I was more concerned about technical limitation.